# Issues with vue-loader

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-loader

I ran into some issues with vue-loader while trying to create a vue project. I started out creating a project with vue init. Next up I added Firebase by running `npm install firebase` and adding `import firebase from "firebase";` and

```
let config = {
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SEND_ID"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

to my main.js file.
When I tried to run this with `npm run serve`, I got the error "Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader/package.json'".
So I tried to install vue-loader through npm, after which I got a different error because I was missing @vue/compiler-sfc.

After I did this the app worked for a very short bit, until I tried to install Vuetify.

I added Vuetify to my main.js and now I'm getting the error

> Error: [VuetifyLoaderPlugin Error] No matching rule for vue-loader found.
> Make sure there is at least one root-level rule that uses vue-loader.

From my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^7.23.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3",
    "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.6",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
```

Comment: did you install vue-loader?

Comment: Does this resolve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929598/vueloaderplugin-error-no-matching-use-for-vue-loader-is-found

Comment: @mateonunez no, i'm not using vue-loader in any way, firebase just won't work if it's not installed for some reason

Comment: @RandyCasburn yeah, with npm

Comment: Add your dependecies sections from your package.json to the question please.

Comment: How did you install vuetify?

Comment: @petey I added it

Comment: @petey I installed vuetify by using the vue add command in my command line, I think (might've been npm install too, but I think vue add uses npm install so there's not really a difference?)

Comment: Good. `vue add` is the correct way